# How not to lose focus on a login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, focus

I have a simple login form with 2 input fields: "username" and "password".
"username" field is focused by default. The problem is that when user clicks outside "username" or "password" fields, the focus is gone (it is neither on "username" nor on "password" fields"). How can I force the focus to be on these 2 fields only ?

In my case, this is a really annoying behavior, so I really want to do this :)

Can I do something like:

```
$("*").focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("my_inputs_class")) {
        // How to stop the focusing process here ?
    }
});
```

?

Comment: Eugh. Please don't try to do this. If users want the focus to be somewhere else, let them have it somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe this very irritating focus behavior is something you were asked to do, so you have little power to do otherwise, but think: is it really worth the trouble? Is it useful? Even necessary?

Comment: @Misha: Welcome to programming a web application!

Comment: This also ruins a lot of text-based browsers. Do not force the focus, In general do not force anything with UI.

Comment: I doubt there are a lot of text-based browsers around which do javascript event handling.

Comment: What if they want to click on the Login button?  Or, even just tab to it?  Enough users just use their keyboard (with little mouse interaction) that this would be insanely annoying.

Comment: Just make sure all the links and buttons on the page are also included in the list of allowable focus items, or the user won't be able to use the keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you **always** want one of your inputs to be focused, fair enough. The way I would do this is to bind each of your inputs `blur()` events so that if it occurs, it goes to the next element.

Here's the markup:

```
<body>
<form method="POST" action=".">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // what are the named fields the user may focus on?
    var allowed = ['username', 'password', 'submit'];
    $.each(allowed, function(i, val) {
        var next = (i + 1) % allowed.length;
        $('input[name='+val+']').bind('blur', function(){
            $('input[name='+allowed[next]+']').focus();
        });
    });
    $('input[name='+allowed[0]+']').focus();
});
```

Comment: +1 for the concept, but the jQuery example could be a little less complex.  -- Slightly cleaner jQuery code at http://www.jsfiddle.net/bKuUV/2/

Comment: Also, naming / setting the ID of a `<input>` to `submit` can cause issues with the jQuery `.submit()` function.  http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6264

Comment: I don't set the `id` of the `input` to submit, so the ticket is not relevant. My example doesn't use `id`s at all, I just don't see how they're necessary to answering the question. I like your use of `next()` though. Also, I don't use `first()` very much but I like that too.

Comment: Oh - And I solved the shift+tab issue with a little `setTimeout` -- http://www.jsfiddle.net/bKuUV/3/ -- feel free to edit in my examples if you want to use them...

Comment: The same bug occurs with `<input name="submit">`  as well as `<input id="submit">` -- http://www.jsfiddle.net/SLAAc/

Answer (score 7):

You could use javascript to set the focus on focusout, but you *really* shoudn't. Forcing focus on those fields would break the normal interaction of the page. It would mean a user couldn't do something as simple as clicking on a link on the page, because focus would always be on those inputs.

Please don't do it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really really want to do this (and you shouldn't) use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of setting a separate event handler on every single HTML element:

```
$('body').delegate('*', 'focus', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("my_inputs_class")) {
    $('#username').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

But consider that this will make unacessible all elements except the two input fields via keyboard navigation (including the submit button, any links on the page etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Set `blur` event handler so it brings back focus to one of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this (in psuedo code):

```
if user || pass blured  
    if user.len > 0 
        pass.setFocus
    else
        user.setFocus
```

Hope you get it.

Comment: It's not good enough because if user enters username and password, and then he wants to change the username, he can't because the focus will be on the password.

Answer (score 0):

Install an `onClick` handler on the `body` element (or a div that covers most of the page). Clicking on the div should then set the focus on the username/password field.

I also suggest to bind <kbd>Return</kbd> in the "username" to "Set focus on password" and <kbd>Return</kbd> in the "password" field to "Submit form".

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the click on links by re-focusing on you inputs after a minimum time interval.

Every time an object gains the focus you check if it has the required class: if not set the focus to the first of the form inputs; this way:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
    $('*').focus(function() { var obj = this; setTimeout(function () {checkFocus(obj)}, 1)});
    })

    function checkFocus(obj) {
        if (!$(obj).hasClass('force_focus')){
            $('input.force_focus:first').focus()
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Extrnal link</a>
    <form><div>
User: <input type="text" name="user" class="force_focus"/><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="force_focus"/><br/>
Other: <input type="text" name="other" class=""/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</div></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is only an idea, you can use a setInterval function to put the focus in the username field, and you can interrupt it when you want with clearInterval function.

```
var A = setInterval(function(){ $('#username').focus();}, 100);
```

... and for interrumpt it, you can do something like this

```
$('#password').focus(function(){ clearInterval(A);});
```